Equivalent definitions of Stopping time
For a discrete filtration, we define a stopping time as ,
Def. A stopping time for the filtration $(g_n)$ is a random variable
$T:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \infty \ \text{such that} $
{ $T=n$ } $ \in g_n \ \text{for all} \ n \ge 0$.
I can show it is equivalent to say { $T\leq n$ } $ \in g_n \ \text{for all} \ n \ge 0$.
But can we prove it is also equivalent to say { $T<n$ } $ \in g_n \ \text{for all} \ n \ge 0$?
One direction is simple, but how to show from { $T<n$ }  to { $T\leq n$ }?

You cannot! They are not equivalent.

There is no equivalence. $\{T < n\} = \{T\leq n-1\}\in g_{n-1}$ so $\{T < n\}$ is already a predictable event at time $n-1$, but $\{T\leq n\}$ can only reasonably be predicted at time $n$ and not before.
